# Cannot connect tomcat container to mysql container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, tomcat8

I have a problem to connect tomcat docker container to docker mysql container.

The error that tomcat says is:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

Then containers haves connection between both if I enter inside container tomcat I can connect to mysql container by

```
mysql -u user -h mysql_container -p
```

The application is configured with hibernate and the library com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource for building a connection pool

I proved with other library connection pool and the error is the same.

Here my configuration files

**conf/catalina/localhost/resource.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Context cookies="false">
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/DB" global="jdbc/DB" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</Context>
```

**conf/server.xml**

```
<GlobalNamingResources>

        <Resource auth="Container"
                  driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                  maxPoolSize="3"
                  minPoolSize="3"
                  acquireIncrement="2"
                  name="jdbc/DB"
                  user="user"
                  password="password"
                  factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
                  type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
                  jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/db?autoReconnect=true"/>

 </GlobalNamingResources>
```

**compose file**

```
    mysqldb:
        container_name: mysql
        image: mysql:v1
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
          MYSQL_DATABASE: db
          MYSQL_USER: user
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: user
          MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: 192.168.20.0/255.255.255.0

        networks:
          app_net:
            ipv4_address: 192.168.20.20
        volumes:
           - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql/
           - mysql-data1:/etc/mysql/

      xml01:
        container_name: xml01
        expose:
          - "8009"
        ports:
          - "8080:8080"
        image: tomcat:v1

        #depends_on:
        # - mysqldb
        networks:
          app_net:
            ipv4_address: 192.168.20.10
        volumes:
                - tomcat_data:/usr/local/tomcat/
        links:
                - mysqldb


    volumes:
      proxy-data:
      mysql-data:
      mysql-data1:

  tomcat_data:

networks:
  app_net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      -
        subnet: 192.168.20.0/24
```

error

```
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.727 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.28
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.729 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Feb 6 2018 23:10:25 UTC
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.729 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.28.0
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.729 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.730 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.15.0-24-generic
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.730 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.730 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.730 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-1~deb9u1-b13
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.730 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.730 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.730 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.731 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.731 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.731 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.731 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.731 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.731 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.731 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.731 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.731 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.17] using APR version [1.5.2].
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.732 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.732 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.735 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017]
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.819 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.832 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.840 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.841 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.842 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 499 ms
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.915 INFO [MLog-Init-Reporter] com.mchange.v2.log.MLog. MLog clients using java 1.4+ standard logging.
21-Aug-2018 15:47:23.975 INFO [main] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry. Initializing c3p0-0.9.5.2 [built 08-December-2015 22:06:04 -0800; debug? true; trace: 10]
21-Aug-2018 15:47:24.041 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
21-Aug-2018 15:47:24.042 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.28
21-Aug-2018 15:47:24.057 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor [/usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/resclick.xml]
21-Aug-2018 15:47:28.622 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
21-Aug-2018 15:47:29.220 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource. Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 2, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, dataSourceName -> 1hge4ui9xpun2k5rhr78s|53f65459, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, forceSynchronousCheckins -> false, forceUseNamedDriverClass -> false, identityToken -> 1hge4ui9xpun2k5rhr78s|53f65459, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://db:3306/resclickdb?autoReconnect=true, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 3, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 3, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> null, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
21-Aug-2018 15:50:03.599 WARNING [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge4ui9xpun2k5rhr78s|53f65459]-HelperThread-#0] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool. com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@7eedbf30 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception:
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor15.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1023)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:997)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:983)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:928)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2407)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2328)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor11.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor9.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1137)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:356)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2504)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2346)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: db
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1280)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:250)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:306)
        ... 20 more

21-Aug-2018 15:50:03.599 WARNING [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge4ui9xpun2k5rhr78s|53f65459]-HelperThread-#2] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool. com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@560ec1f4 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception:
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor15.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1023)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:997)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:983)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:928)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2407)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2328)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor11.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor9.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1137)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:356)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2504)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2346)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: db
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1280)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:250)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:306)
        ... 20 more

21-Aug-2018 15:50:03.603 WARNING [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge4ui9xpun2k5rhr78s|53f65459]-HelperThread-#0] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool. Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@28a3708d is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
21-Aug-2018 15:50:03.606 WARNING [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge4ui9xpun2k5rhr78s|53f65459]-HelperThread-#2] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool. Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@28a3708d is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
21-Aug-2018 15:50:03.608 WARNING [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge4ui9xpun2k5rhr78s|53f65459]-HelperThread-#1] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool. com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@62146d03 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception:
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor15.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1023)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:997)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:983)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:928)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2407)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2328)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor11.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor9.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1137)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:356)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2504)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2346)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: db
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1280)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:250)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:306)
        ... 20 more

21-Aug-2018 15:50:03.613 WARNING [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge4ui9xpun2k5rhr78s|53f65459]-HelperThread-#1] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool. Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@28a3708d is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
```

Thank You

Best Regards

Comment: Is `mysql` a dns Name in `mysql:3306`? I guess you are working with a local db so it must be `localhost:3306` or the ip address

Comment: Is the name of container in compose file :
        container_name: **mysql**

Comment: But i guess it is not a dns Name. The URL can not work with Container names

Answer (score 0):

In tomcat use the container name of your mysql-container instead of the IP, also use the internal port and not the external one

Comment: I don't understand when you saying "use the internal port"  there is a binding port 3306:3306 in compose file version 3.  If I enter into tomcat container I can do a telnet to mysql container 3306 port. And if I install a mysql client in tomcat container, I can access to mysql container by mysql client from tomcat container.  Both access I did  by name

Comment: Can you get tomcat to print out a more detailed error message and/or code? Would be handy to see if tomcat didn't find the host, was denied or has troubles authenticating with the new authentication method of MySQL 8 (if you use that version)

Comment: I print out the error, I change to mysql:5.6 and it has the same error. This environment is in production without docker container and works fine. It doesn't works on docker environment container

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this modification in configuration tomcat compose file.

```
 environment:
            DATABASE_HOST: db
            DATABASE_USER: user
            DATABASE_PASSWORD: password
            DATABASE_NAME: db
            DATABASE_PORT: "3306"
```

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25562

Thank You.